# Clean up a remote machine's temporary directory: How do I identify files that are in use? (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have a number of remote machines whose temporary directories get full. (The are Selenium / webdriver grid remotes). I have a powershell script that identifies the files and directories that need to be cleaned. The command in use looks something like this (excluding complexities of the various machines and directories):

```
gci $env:TEMP -Recurse| Remove-Item -ErrorAction Continue -Recurse
```

The problem is that this takes far too long when some files are in use. Locally, I could join to the output of handles (parsing would be a little ugly), but that would be more complicated on a remote machine. Among other things, I'd need to verify that WinRM was configured correctly, handles was in path, etc.

Is there a simpler way to identify that a file is in use? Ideally one that can be filtered on via Powershell (which includes .NET). I'm familiar with a variety of other scripting languages (ruby, python, perl).

Comment: Good question. I don't know how to do what you ask. when I built a script to clean the temp dir, I decided to remove files that fit a particular set of criteria: the name conforms to a known set of patterns (*.tmp, etc), they are more than 1 week old, and a few other things.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool I've found for listing open files is the [SysInternals tool handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) e.g.:

```
$openFiles = @(handle $env:TEMP | Foreach {($_ -split ": ")[3]} | Select -Unique)
```

Comment: The snippet is clever (doesn't quite work, tho. I will tweak it and re-post.). This would require executing on the remote machine, but there may be no other way.

Comment: The output of handle.exe is text so we're back to parsing text output.  Depending on the version of handle.exe the output format could be different.  I need to ping the SysInternals folks to provide an option to output in CSV format.

Comment: Posted on SysInternals forum in case anybody else wants to chime in - http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic27806_post134498.html#134498

Comment: I now have a reliable handle parsing function, but there are a file files that fail (presumably they are intermittently in use) function getFileNameFromHande($handleOutput) {
 $start = $handleOutput.IndexOf(":\")
 if($Start -lt 0) { 
  return [String]::Empty 

 }
 return $handleOutput.SubString($start - 1)
}

Comment: I now have a solution that combines the handle output with last access time. I'll post the full script after I can clean it up.